# Include CSS triangle in dropdown transition

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a regular Bootstrap navbar with a toggle button to show the navbar-collapse on click. I added a triangle above the menu so that it points to the hamburger button. I want the dropdown menu button to show with a transition but then there's a second delay until the triangle shows up. How can I get the triangle to show up in the transition the same time the menu does?

[Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/g8d0nLzlIE)

```
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
      <div class="navbar-header">

        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>

 <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li><a href="#">All Watches</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown"> 
      <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button">
      Watches by Brand <span class="caret"></span>
    </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Audemars Piguet</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Bell &amp; Ross</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Blancpain</a></li>  
        </ul>
    </li>
      <li><a href="#"></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"></a></li>
       <li class="visible-xs"><a href="#" class="green"> <i class="ion-android-arrow-back"></i> main site</a></li>
    </ul>

  </div>
```

CSS:

```
.navbar-collapse.in {overflow-y: visible;}
.navbar-collapse:before {border-bottom: 20px solid #fff; border-left: 20px solid transparent; border-right: 20px solid transparent; top: -10px; content: ""; position: absolute; left: 27px; margin-left: -10px; width: 0;height: 0;}
```

Comment: I don't want to add so many screenfuls of code. I thought a bootply is enough.

Comment: Ok I've just submitted multiple questions here and a bootply has always been enough. I guess I learned something new today, then.

Answer (score 1):

For the triangle to show when the menu is clicked open `overflow: visible;` would need to be applied to `.navbar-collapse` along with a `min-height` rule (*in the posted example it's written differently because I changed some rules*) but some rules you have can be reduced since they may be conflicting.

All the rules to make the mobile nav constant can have the media query removed since there won't be any change there which should help to simplify how the rest could be written.

**Working Example:** (* All the rules are prepended with `nav` so they work with Stackovers editor, otherwise they shouldn't be necessary.)

```css
nav.navbar {
  background-color: #27402a;
  padding: 20px 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  border: 0;
}
nav.navbar .navbar-header {
  float: none;
}
nav.navbar .navbar-toggle {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 20px;
  border: 0;
  z-index: 1055;
}
nav.navbar .navbar-toggle:hover,
nav.navbar .navbar-toggle:focus {
  background-color: transparent;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  border: 0;
}
nav.navbar .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 26px;
}
nav.navbar .navbar-collapse {
  border-top: 1px solid transparent;
  border-left: 1px solid transparent;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 88px;
  width: 250px;
  background-color: white;
}
nav.navbar .navbar-collapse:before {
  content: "";
  margin-top: -40px;
  margin-left: 21px;
  border-top: 20px solid transparent;
  border-right: 20px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 20px solid white;
  border-left: 20px solid transparent;
}
nav.navbar .navbar-collapse.collapse {
  display: none!important;
  height: auto!important;
  overflow: visible!important
}
nav.navbar .navbar-nav {
  float: none!important;
  margin-top: 7.5px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 600;
}
nav.navbar .navbar-nav > li {
  float: none;
}
nav.navbar .navbar-nav > li > a {
  color: #000;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  font-size: 16px;
}
nav.navbar .collapse.in {
  display: block!important;
}
nav.navbar .collapsing {
  transition: height 5ms linear;
}
nav.navbar .navbar-nav .dropdown-menu > li > a,
nav.navbar .navbar-nav .dropdown-menu > li > a:hover,
nav.navbar .navbar-nav .dropdown-menu > li > a:focus {
  color: #000;
}
nav.navbar .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu {
  position: static;
  float: none;
  width: auto;
  margin-top: 0;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  font-size: 13px;
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  nav.navbar {
    padding: 5px;
  }
  nav.navbar .navbar-collapse {
    top: 58px;
    left: 0;
  }
  nav.navbar .navbar-collapse:before {
    margin-left: 11px;
    margin-top: -30px;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">

  <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
  </div>

  <div class="navbar-collapse collapse no-transition">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li><a href="#">All Watches</a>
      </li>
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button">
          Watches by Brand <span class="caret"></span>
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Link 1</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Link 2</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Link 3</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Link 1</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Link 2</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Link 3</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Link 4</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Link 5</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Link 6</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Link 7</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Link 8</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Link 9</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Link 10</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</nav>

<div class="container">
  <div class="alert alert-success">
    Hello
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```